# Calculate lat/long

Tags: java, floating-point, latitude-longitude

Can any please help me to find out the algorithm of calculating latitude and longitude from 8 byte value?

8- byte value - **A027AFDF5D984840** and It's longitude is **49.1903648** 
8- byte value - **3AC7253383DD4B40** and It's latitude is **55.7305664**

Also if possible then please tell me how to calculate floating point value of **0000000000805A40** as **106.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specific to longitude and latitude calculation.  Given that you have 8 bytes to work with in your examples, what you are looking to do is convert a byte array to double precision floating point values.  The process is the same for all three examples.

To find the floating point value, you need to deal with the byte array at the bit level.  An explanation of the process is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/801146/704402).  Or check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

To get you started, in your first example, you will be dealing with the bytes in the order of 40, 48, 98, 5D and so on.  Breaking down the first two bytes, 40 and 48 (0100 0000 0100 1000), you have enough information to get the sign bit (0) and the exponent bit range (100 0000 0100 -> 1028).  From here, continue listing out the 52 remaining bits to determine the fractional portion of the number.  If you follow the calculations at the links above, you will see the floating point values you expect from your examples.

As a side note, some programming languages provide a method of doing this conversion for you.  Depending on what language you are using, there is no need to reinvent the wheel here.

**EDIT: Example**

To convert the byte array to a double precision floating point value, we will need three pieces of information from the byte array: the **sign bit (S)**, the **exponent (E)** and the **fraction (F)**.  The first thing to do is create your 64 bit representation of the 8 byte array.  As I mentioned above, you will use the bytes in "reverse" order (little-endian if you want to do reading on the topic).  I will use only the first four bytes as they will be enough to illustrate the process.

40 48 98 5D ==> 01000000 01001000 10011000 01011101

I will refer to the bits above in the order of 0 being leftmost.

**Sign bit:**
This is the 0th bit in the array above.  In this case, **S** is 0.  The sign bit is exactly what you'd think it would be, it determines whether the floating point result will be negative or positive.

**Exponent:**
Bits 1-11 determine the exponent.  In the example, the exponent **E** is 100 0000 0100 ==> 1028.

**Fraction:**
The remaining bits, 12-63 determine the fraction.  I only illustrated bits 12-31 to show how the process works:   1000 10011000 01011101....

The fractional bits are not converted to a decimal value.  Instead, you need to iterate through them paying attention to the bits which are set (1, not 0).  The index of the bits is what is important here.  Consider the fraction bits indexed starting at 1 increasing from left to right to 20.  Again, in the full example (bits 12-63), this indexing would be 1 to 52.

The fraction is found by summing each i'th bit that is set using this expression: 2^-i.  For this example this means we are dealing with indexes 1,5,8,9,14,16,17,18,20.

The first four indexes will give us enough precision for the purposes of the example:

**F** = (2^-1) + (2^-5) + (2^-8) + (2^-9) + ... = 0.5 + 0.03125 + 0.00390625 + 0.001953125 = 0.537109375

The final value **V** is found by applying the formula:

**V** = -1^S * 2^(E-1023) * (1 + F) = -1^0 + 2^(1028-1023) * 1.537109375 = 49.1875

This is a good approximation of your goal value of 49.1903648.  If you were to continue using the full fractional bit range in the manner I showed you, your final value will match.

Lastly, since you mentioned you are using Java, have you taken a look at using the `ByteBuffer` class and the `getDouble` function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getDouble%28%29)?

Comment: Thanks Adam for help. I am trying this in JAVA. As per your suggestion I have tried to find out the method of doing this conversion but I have not found anything helpful. Also as I am new to lower level bit manipulation I am not getting the conversion method provided in above link. Can you please explain conversion for any one of the value? Thanks,<br/>Sachin Deshmukh

Comment: Good. In future posts, you may want to assign more tags to your questions to help them get noticed.