# How to normalize a mantissa

Tags: c, floating-point, double, normalization

I'm trying to convert an int into a custom float, in which the user specifies the amount of bits reserved for the exp and mantissa.

My function takes in an `int value` and `int exp` to represent the number as ***value * 2<sup>exp</sup>***. E.g. value = 12 and exp = 4 returns 192.

What is the process to change these?

It's *"move the binary point and adjust the exponent"* but I have no idea what this means. I don't understand what the exponent bias is. The only info I have is that you add a number to your exponent but I don't understand why.

Comment: It is the binary equivalent of 0.01 --> 1e-2 IOW: shift the mantissa right/left and add/substract the count to the exponent.

Comment: If value is 12 and we have that in a binary value it's `00001100`. That needs to be shifted over to be `11000000 x 2^-4`, and then we forget about the leftmost bit (since it's "always" 1) and just say this is `[1]1000000 x 2^-4`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I don't understand the process I need to do to change these"? Do you mean  you aren't sure how to change them when you do addition/multiplication?

Comment: @eigenchris Like how do I take decimal 12, and make it a normalized mantissa, then adjust the exp part accordingly

Comment: @U2EF1 so how do I know how many times it needs to be shifted over? Like if the user specifices 4 bits for the mantissa, and the value is 3, how do I know to shift 0011 over to 1000? Could I so something like get max_val = pow(2,<specified mant. bits>)-1 then shift value(0011) right until value > max_val, and have a counter keep track of how many times I do this?

Answer (score 42):

A floating point number is *normalized* when we force the integer part of its mantissa to be exactly `1` and allow its fraction part to be whatever we like.

For example, if we were to take the number `13.25`, which is `1101.01` in binary, `1101` would be the integer part and `01` would be the fraction part.

I could represent `13.25` as `1101.01*(2^0)`, but this isn't normalized because the integer part is not `1`. **However**, we are allowed to shift the mantissa to the right one digit if we increase the exponent by 1:

```
  1101.01*(2^0)
= 110.101*(2^1)
= 11.0101*(2^2)
= 1.10101*(2^3)
```

This representation `1.10101*(2^3)` is the normalized form of `13.25`.

---

That said, we know that normalized floating point numbers **will always come in the form `1.fffffff * (2^exp)`**

For efficiency's sake, we don't bother storing the `1` integer part in the binary representation itself, we just pretend it's there. So if we were to give your custom-made float type 5 bits for the mantissa, we would know the bits `10100` **would actually stand for `1.10100`**.

Here is an example with the standard 23-bit mantissa:

[image]

---

As for the exponent bias, let's take a look at the standard 32-bit `float` format, which is broken into 3 parts: 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, and 23 mantissa bits:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
```

The exponents `00000000` and `11111111` have special purposes (like representing `Inf` and `NaN`), so  with 8 exponent bits, we could represent 254 different exponents, say `2^1` to `2^254`, for example. But what if we want to represent `2^-3`? How do we get negative exponents?

The format fixes this problem by **automatically subtracting 127 from the exponent**. Therefore:

- `0000 0001` would be `1  -127 = -126`
- `0010 1101` would be `45 -127 = -82`
- `0111 1111` would be `127-127 = 0`
- `1001 0010` would be `136-127 = 9`

This changes the exponent range from `2^1 ... 2^254` to `2^-126 ... 2^+127` so we can represent negative exponents.

Comment: @eipenchris, can you please tell me who to identify the  integer  part

Comment: @kashyap the integer part is the part to the left of the decimal point (also called the radix point).

Answer (score 7):

Tommy -- chux and eigenchris, along with the others have provided excellent answers, but if I am looking at your comments correctly, you still seem to be struggling with the nuts-and-bolts of "how would I take this info and then use this in creating a custom float representation where the user specifies the amount of bits for the exponent?" Don't feel bad, it is a clear as mud the first dozen times you go through it. I think I can take a stab at clearing it up.

You are familiar with the IEEE754-Single-Precision-Floating-Point representation of:

```
IEEE-754 Single Precision Floating Point Representation of (13.25)

  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
 |s|      exp      |                  mantissa                   |
```

That the `1-bit sign-bit`, `8-bit biased exponent` (in 8-bit excess-127 notation), and the remaining `23-bit mantissa`.

When you allow the user to choose the number of bits in the exponent, you are going to have to **rework** the exponent notation to work with the new user-chosen limit.

**What will that change?**

- Will it change the `sign-bit` handling -- **No**.
- Will it change the `mantissa` handling -- **No** 
  (you will still convert the mantissa/significand to "hidden bit" format).

So the only thing you need to focus on is `exponent handling`.

How would you approach this? Recall, the current 8-bit exponent is in what is called **excess-127 notation** (where 127 represents the largest value for `7` bits allowing any bias to be contained and expressed within the current `8-bit` limit. If your user chooses 6 bits as the exponent size, then what? You will have to provide a similar method to insure you have a fixed number to represent your new **excess-##** notation that will work within the user limit.

Take a `6-bit` user limit, then a choice for the unbiased exponent value could be tried as `31` (the largest values that can be represented in `5-bits`). To that you could apply the same logic (taking the 13.25 example above). Your binary representation for the number is `1101.01` to which you move the decimal `3 positions to the left` to get `1.10101` which gives you an exponent bias of `3`.

In your `6-bit exponent` case you would add `3 + 31` to obtain your `excess-31 notation` for the exponent: `100010`, then put the mantissa in "hidden bit" format (i.e. drop the leading `1` from `1.10101` resulting in your new custom Tommy Precision Representation:

```
IEEE-754 Tommy Precision Floating Point Representation of (13.25)

  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
 |s|    exp    |                    mantissa                     |
```

With `1-bit sign-bit`, `6-bit biased exponent` (in 6-bit excess-31 notation), and the remaining `25-bit mantissa`.

The same rules would apply to reversing the process to get your floating point number back from the above notation. (just using `31` instead of `127` to back the bias out of the exponent)

Hopefully this helps in some way. I don't see much else you can do if you are truly going to allow for a user-selected exponent size. Remember, the IEEE-754 standard wasn't something that was guessed at and a lot of good reasoning and trade-offs went into arriving at the 1-8-23 sign-exponent-mantissa layout. However, I think your exercise does a great job at requiring you to firmly understand the standard.

Now totally lost and **not addressed** in this discussion is what effects this would have on the range of numbers that could be represented in this `Custom Precision Floating Point Representation`. I haven't looked at it, but the primary limitation would seem to be a reduction in the `MAX/MIN` that could be represented.

Answer (score 6):

"Normalization process" converts the inputs into a select range.

[binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) expects the significand (not mantissa) to be in the range `1.0 <= s < 2.0` unless the number has a minimum exponent.

> Example:
>   `value = 12, exp = 4` is the same as
>   `value = 12/(2*2*2), exp = 4 + 3`
>   `value = 1.5, exp = 7`

Since the significand always has a leading digit of `1` (unless the number has a minimum exponent), there is no need to store it.  And rather than storing the exponent as `7`, a bias of 127 is added to it.

> value = 1.5 decimal --> 1.1000...000 binary  --> 0.1000...000 stored binary  (23 bits in all)
>    exp = 7 --> bias exp 7 + 127 --> 134 decimal --> 10000110 binary

The binary pattern stored is the concatenation of the "sign", "significand with a leading 1 bit implied" and a "bias exponent"

```
0 10000110 1000...000 (1 + 8 + 23 = 32 bits)
```

When the biased exponent is `0` - the minimum value, the implied bit is `0` and so small numbers like `0.0` can be stored.

When the biased exponent is `255` - the maximum value, data stored no longer represents finite numbers but "infinity" and "Not-a-numbers".

Check the referenced link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a comment posted on 'how to do this in code':
(Assuming it's an IEEE float)

A) Extract an unsigned 'exponent' and 'mantissa' from the IEEE float.

i)     `exp = 0x7F800000 & yourFloatVar;`

//this takes bit b1 through b8 from the float. (b0 is the signed bit, b9 and on is the mantissa)

ii) `exp = exp >> 23;` //shift right so this exponent is right-oriented

iii) `exp += 127;` //add in the bias (127 is for 32-bit only)

iv) `mantissa = 0x007FFFFF & yourFloatVar;` //take last 23 bits from float

B) Normalizing

i)

```
while(true)
{
    if( ((mantissa & 0xC0000000) != 0x80000000)
         &&((mantissa & 0xC0000000) != 0x40000000) )
    {
        mantissa = mantissa << 1;
        exponent--;
    }
    else //AKA the float has been normalized
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

if leading 2 bits aren't '01' or '10' (this is a property of 2's complement - the condition to normalize), then shift over the mantissa and decrement the exponent.

I want to note that this isn't at all the most efficient algorithm for doing this; I just wanted to make the steps clear. Hope I didn't miss anything!

Answer (score -1):

To normalize a mantissa you place the decimal point to the left of the leftmost non-zero digit

for example

represent 10.11 base 2 in normalize form

= 0.1011 base 2 * 2 to the second power

the base of two is because you are working with binary numbers and the power of +ve 2 is because you moved the decimal point left two times. Remember that only 4 bits are used for the mantizza

so the mantizza would be 1011

Comment: can you give a more concrete example on how this is done in code? Like I understand 3.1416 in binary would be 11.00100100001111... so I need to normalize it to1.100100100001111... x 2^1 I get the abstract part but I dont understand how to actually implement this