# How to portably write double data type to file in C

Tags: c, file, io, binary

I need to store `double` values in a file in a way that will be portable. I know I can just write them in human readable form like `1.23456789`, but I am hoping to save space by writing them as binary.

I know how to write binary to a file, but is there a way to do that in a way in which the resulting file will be the same regardless of the machine on which the code was compiled and executed? I am hoping to be able to read/write such files across machines in this way.

Comment: The easy normal way is to use a cross-platform serialization library like msgpack or Google protocol buffers

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: it's overkill if the *only* thing you need to serialize is doubles, but that's exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: Yeah I actually need to write some integers too, except I thought I had that figured out since there are fixed size integer data types provided (int16_t, int32_t) but I forgot that the endianness can change from machine to machine. So I'll probably use msgpack. Thanks1

Comment: You're trying to save space because storage is so expensive?  Are you writing out more than 1 million doubles?  Just use a JSON library.

Comment: Yeah I do write a lot of doubles. Why JSON and why not msgpack?

Comment: @nc404 - Typical usage of JSON will make your data 1) somewhat self-documenting, 2) human readable, 3) easily changeable, 4) readable by many languages, and 5) readable by many languages natively and 6) without compilation changes automatically required for data changes.  It's also (usually) 7) larger and slower.  Typical usage of google protocol buffers will give you 1, 3, & 4.

Comment: It is not possible to write `double` values in a format that is universally portable across C implementations. Proof: C defines a floating-point value to be a numeral in a base multiplied by the base to a power (C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 3). The numeral length and the base are implementation-defined. Some numbers that are representable in one C implementation, such as 1/10 in a base-ten implementation, are not representable in others. Therefore, regardless of what string is written to a file, it is not possible to reconstruct the value in a C implementation that uses binary floating-point.

Comment: If you can assume the systems involved use the same binary-base format for `double` (or at least use some binary-base format and each system is capable of representing all required values), then use the `%a` format for input and output. This uses a hexadecimal notation that represents values easily and exactly (that is, without any rounding needed).

Comment: If you need to compress further than that, and again can assume a binary base, then write a bit for the sign, the bits for the significand, and the exponent in binary. You can obtain the bits for the significand and the exponent using `frexp`. You will need to decide how to encode NaNs and infinities.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I've been pondering your comments.  If we assume typical double usage where the range and precision of a 4-byte float is insufficient, but the range and precision of an 8-byte float is massive overkill, such a case being able to translate `124.56054` from `text` to `IEEE double` to `base-ten double` back to `IEEE double` and back to `text` without the text changing, could we then consider an implementation "portable enough" for a specific use/implementation?  I'm assuming your definition of `portable` is very strict, and would like to make sure that's correct.

Comment: @zzxyz: It is likely some portable representation can be defined, but the problem statement needs clarification. I am not sure what is meant by going from text to IEEE double to base-ten double to IEEE double to text. That is more conversions than is needed for “I have a floating-point value in my program, and I write some data to a file, and I read it in another program, and I end with the original value (or something within a defined distance) in the new program.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil (I was imagining a trip from one computer's UI to maybe a weird server back to another computer's UI).  I think your first sentence answers my question well enough for my purposes, which is basically idle curiosity :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always externalize the number according to IEEE 754. This is also the most used format in current CPUs, but if you want to be portable, you have to calculate the relevant fields (sign/exponent/fraction) in the required precision programmatically instead of directly using the in-memory representation of the current platform.

Another alternative is using fixed-point numbers. If the number range and precision you want to represent allows it, this might be the easier alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine you're using to serialize the `double` value uses IEEE 754 double precision for `double` values, you can store the sign, exponent, and mantissa separately, so that you can use that information to rebuild the double value in whatever other system you want to load it on:

```
typedef union _DI
{
    double d;
    uint64_t bits;
} DI;


DI foo;
uint64_t mask = 0x8000000000000000, sign, exp, mantissa, base;
int i;

foo.d = 3.141;
sign = !!(foo.bits & mask);

mask = 0x7FF0000000000000;
exp = ((foo.bits & mask) >> 52) - 1023;

mask = 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF;
mantissa = (foo.bits & mask);
```

Do note that the mantissa needs to be [normalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800565/how-to-normalize-a-mantissa) as well.

Comment: C has `frexp` to provide the significand and the exponent; there is no need for unions or assuming an IEEE-754 format.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is no.  There's no binary portable way to write floating point numbers in binary form.  Even if you follow the IEEE-752 document, you'll find that you can store the bytes conforming a floating point in different orders (like big/little endian forms for integers)

There are several IETF protocols (most notable IPFIX protocol) that define a format for transmitting IEEE-752 floating point numbers into what is called (there) network format.  This forces the number to be written in a major to minor weight basis, but for example this forces low endian machines (like intel's) to swap the bytes on reading/writing to the wire.

So, what is the people doing? well, if you want to conserve your data, you had better to define your own format and follow it always in your projects. In a way independent of the architecture.  If you have the luck of being the first, when others need to access your data, you can tell them the way those data is stored and all can follow your specification, instead of being you who has to adapt to theirs.